# What is the exact meaning of the PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance returned in the FILE_STORAGE_INFO struct?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, file-io, filesystems

The documentation for the data members of the [`FILE_STORAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447302.aspx) struct returned through the [`GetFileInformationByHandleEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364953.aspx) function is somewhat terse.

The documentation explains `PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance` as *"Bytes per sector for optimal performance for writes."*

The name seems to suggest that this is a size smaller than the physical sector size of the storage device. But I'm not sure whether that makes sense.

Maybe the name is misleading and `PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance` is the optimal logical block size for writing, i.e. similar to Posix's [stat.st_blksize](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html)?

Does anyone know more?

Answer (score 2):

If the `STORAGE_INFO_FLAGS_ALIGNED_DEVICE` flag is also set, it means that the physical sector size is smaller than the logical sector size. (Otherwise, a logical sector may not map to a physical sector.) Otherwise, it's probably just a recommendation from the driver.